# C# send video from webcam via TCP/IP

Tags: c#

I use directshow .net to record video from webcam and save it to file, but how can I stream video via TCP/IP to another computer? I don't mind if I can't use directshow .net to do that. I want somehow stream video from webcam to another computer. Any tips or advices?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should first show us what have you tried so far before asking for help. See http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/ for a good explanation.

Comment: Any answer would be very long for SO. You require a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the .net vlc based wrapper -
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/libvlcnet/